# How to use Laravel Sanctum token in front-end application

Tags: laravel, token, sanctum

I think I am getting confused about how to use Laravel Sanctum tokens. Here is my problem

I have a single application which contains both an API and a front-end. The reason for this is the API will be useable by other external sources. But I also want my front-end to use the same API. Otherwise I will be re-creating all my controllers to do the same thing the API controllers do

So users cannot register themselves. An admin will register them and assign them one of three tokens - each token with its own abilities

Now, when a user logs in and goes to the "product" page for example, I want to check that their token has the ability to read products. Some tokens have that ability, some do not. My application controller has the following code to call the API

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = Http::withToken('my-token')
        ->get('https://my-domain/api/v1/products');
    
    return view('products', ['products' => $products->json()]);
}
```

But what do I put in the `my-token` string? Every user's token will be different. I cannot get the token because it is encoded in the database and not retrievable.

I am sure the problem is my approach, so how would I achieve this?

Comment: If understand correctly, you don't need to send request to your api in the same app, just call api controller. I think that you don't need to validate API tokens abilities when user is already authenticated.

Comment: But different users have different permissions. When I hit the API controller, I need to check that the user's permission level allows them to perform the action. This is where the bearer token comes in as that contains individual abilities

Comment: Is user in your example logged in via session or token? Does every user has it own token or users are using same token? If every user have own token you can do: $user->tokens->first()->can('server:update')

Comment: Every user has their own token and they are logged in via a session.  the question is more about how I can get their token to pass to an API. The API has all the security set to it based on the token's permissions. I am trying to avoid re-writing all my controllers when the API already does everything I need. I just need to know how to get the user's token to pass to the API. As a temporary solution, I am storing the user's token in their session, but that doesn't seem very secure to me

Comment: I think that storing in session in fine, that data stays on server. I would recommend using some ACL, like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission so that both API and web can use same system.